# Haskell - Need help understanding this split function

Tags: haskell

I need help understanding the following Haskell function,

```hs
split l = rr++[ll]
            where
              split = foldl
                        ( \ (c,a) e ->
                               case c of
                                [] -> ([e],a)  
                                _ -> if e*(head c) < 0
                                     then ([e],a++[c])
                                     else (c++[e],a))
                        ([],[])
              (ll,rr) = split l

> split [1,2,3,-1,-2,7,4,-3,-5,-6,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[-1,-2],[7,4],[-3,-5,-6],[2,3]]
```

It splits consecutive numbers with the same sign in separate lists as seen above. In Scheme, the tracer function was so helpful in evaluating expressions step by step, but unfortunately, GHCi doesn't have such a feature. Please help me step through the code. Thanks!

Note: I understand the foldl part of the function. It is the pattern matching part (`split l = rr++[ll]` and `(ll,rr) = split l`) which really confuses me!

Comment: Which pattern-matching part - do you mean the case expression? What about it confuses you?

Comment: I mean, the algorithm itself is intensely confusing and, well, downright perverse :) – try it on a list that starts with 0. But you should be clear if it's that or the syntax or what that you're stuck on.

Comment: For what it's worth, GHCi _can_ do tracing. I don't remember how at the moment, though...

Comment: I understand the case expression part of the foldl. split l = rr++[ll] and (ll,rr) = split l confuses me, Thanks! :) Yeah, asked it elsewhere and was told that it was bad code!

Comment: I edited the question to include your clarification here, I hope you don't mind (please feel free to do it differently)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what may be confusing you here is that in fact the `split` inside the `where` is in fact entirely different from the `split` at the top level – the inner one "shadows" the outer one, just like local variables override global ones. The following code does the exact same thing:

```hs
split l = rr++[ll]
            where
              notSplit = foldl
                        ( \ (c,a) e ->
                               case c of
                                [] -> ([e],a)  
                                _ -> if e*(head c) < 0
                                     then ([e],a++[c])
                                     else (c++[e],a))
                        ([],[])
              (ll,rr) = notSplit l
```

So we call `notSplit` on the input list, which returns a tuple `(ll,rr)`, then we calculate `rr ++ [ll]` and return that.

(As my comment said above, the algorithm is needlessly obscure, inefficient, and incorrect on lists including zeroes. But that's another issue entirely).

Comment: Thanks, I did think the split inside is the same as the split outside. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Think about exactly what the `foldl` expression produces. As it goes through the list, it accumulates a tuple `(c, a)`. The first element of this tuple, `c`, is always a list of numbers. `a` is a list of lists of numbers---which happens to be what you want to return.

When you get a new number, if it has the same sign as the numbers in `c`, you add it to `c`. If it has a *different* sign than what's currently in `c`, you take all of `c` and put it into `a`.

At the very end, you get a tuple of the last value of `c` and `a`. `a` is almost exactly the result you want, except it isn't complete: you need to add `c` to it. So the very end of the expression

```
(ll, rr) = split l
```

takes the result of `split` (which is `c` and `a`) and assigns `c` to `ll` and `a` to `rr`. The final answer is then just `rr` with `ll` appended to the end.

Comment: Your explanation was really clear! Thank you! :) I will upvote your answer when I can.